# how to convert a XML table to HTML table using lex(flex) yacc(bison)

Tags: html, xml, dom, yacc, lex

```
**from this type of xml code (program will take this type of xml code as input)**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="bookstore.xsl"?>
    <bookstore>
      <book category="cooking">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
      </book>
      <book category="web" cover="paperback">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
      </book>
    </bookstore>
```

**I want my program to return this html file for corresponding XML file above**

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Bookstore</th>
                    <th>Book</th>
                    <th>title</th>
                    <th>author</th>
                    <th>year</th>
                    <th>price</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Everyday Italian</td>
                    <td>Giada De Laurentiis</td>
                    <td>2005</td>
                    <td>30.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Learning XML</td>
                    <td>Erik T. Ray</td>
                    <td>2003</td>
                    <td>39.95</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

do not need to consider all other type of xml file , if the file does not contain a table it will call yyerror from yyparse . There can be more than one table in the code and a table can contain another table .

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Would that not just be done by the xsl ?

Comment: It's hard to interpret this question in any way other than as a request to write a fairly complicated application based on an inadequate specification and without compensation. As such, it really doesn't fit into SO, or afaik any other SE community. VTC.